# Is it necessary to delete branches from Git Repository?

Tags: git, version-control

Over time on projects a large number of branches gets created by multiple developers. Is it a good practice to remove old, merged Git branches from repository?

What are the advantages and disadvantages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: It is technically not necessary, unless you have a *very* high number where filesystem limits kick in or your web UI/tools start struggling with the unusual amount of branches.

There is no obvious disadvantage with removing the old branches **if** your merge commits contain a reference of the branch from which the merge occurred (for documentation reasons). Thats the default case with Git, if you use `git merge branchX` – the message reads `Merge branch "branchX" into branchY` (usually into master).

If you manually modify the message and delete the merged branch, there is no way to find out the branch name afterwards.

The main advantage to me seems to be a tidy project, with only active branches existing, especially when you’re using **feature branches**.

I would personally not delete **release branches**, as you never know when e.g. a critical security update is necessary even for ancient branches, but that depends on your project of course.